# Boost compilation error with python

Tags: c++, python, boost, embed

I'm new to the boost C++ library and I'm trying to use boost with python. Whenever I compile my simple test program I get an error:

```
error: pyconfig.h: No such file or dirctory
```

(followed by thousand more errors which I'm sure are because of this missing header).
I downloaded boost from it's website and then built the library. I still have no idea why that file is missing and how to get it. Please help!

I'm using code::blocks MinGW compiler and I have pointed code blocks to the boost folder as a search directory for headers as well as libraries.
Here's my simple program:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                        "print ’Today is’,ctime(time())\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently do not have the CPython headers in your include path. Just having `boost::python` is not enough, you need Python itself, too.

Comment: Thanks ThiefMaster i did had python installed just didn't pointed code::blocks to it's include directory.